# Testing HTTPS authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, https, nsurlconnection

I'm developing a piece of code in Objective-C for performing HTTP/HTTPS requests faster. This code will be inserted in a library containing the most common performed operations. I'm searching for a server with which testing HTTPS requests which need authentication.

Particularly I've seen that the iOS standard library has the class NSURLConnection. The NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol has the method connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:
and this is what I want to test with my class.

Is there something? I searched on Google but I found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

yes you are right, you will need to use `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` from [NSURLConnectionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) here is some example usage

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return YES;
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm searching for a server through which testing these methods.